# Haraka Mail Server + Laravel

Tags: laravel, smtp, mail-server

Is Haraka-server is compatible with PHP ?, I tried to implement SMTP-Server with Haraka + Laravel(Crudbooster).

Haraka running with 25. I have already test with Swaks for send email and it works well i recieved the email.

But when im tried to test with Laravel with mail_driver smtp port 25, it's not responding in Haraka-server ?, Is there any miss configuration ?, I tried with postfix it work well.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel doesn't care about what mail server you use, as long as it can login over SMTP and send mail.

Anyway, port 25 is almost always closed. Pick a new port.

587
26
465 (with SSL)

Comment: but postfix workfine!, haraka not responding send mail, and laravel show bug like there is no smtp. and i tried it in vps ? is there any idea ?

Comment: @AcepMuhamadSaepuloh Yes, Haraka isn't setup correctly, then.

Comment: anyone ? @Ohgodwhy why haraka server listen 25 and postfix listen 25 not conflict ?